# Android - How to use startForegroundService() and startForeground() for API-28?

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I'm currently researching how to create a floating foreground bubble chathead service.
However, I've noticed that all the Libraries I've attempted to use, don't work on API-28.
I believe this is due to the new restrictioins mentioned [here in the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#migration).

It essentially states that if I'm calling a Service that shows things in the foreground:
I must call `startForegroundService()` instead of `startService()`.

Furthermore it states that:
"After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to call the service's `startForeground()` method to show the new service's user-visible notification."

I believe this is possibly the reason I can't get these foreground chathead Libraries to work.

**Could somebody possibly provide an example of how I'm supposed to implement these?**
Please and thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        // Create the channel for the notification
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        startForegroundService(new Intent(ForegroundService.this, ForegroundService.class));
        //We only need to call this for SDK 26+, since startForeground always has to be called after startForegroundService.
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
    }
    else {
        startService(new Intent(ForegroundService.this, ForegroundService.class));
    }
```

Also, this project is a good base to start with for implementing a ForegroundService:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService

Comment: So what you're saying is, for API-26+, I also need to create a Notification Channel, if I'm starting a Foreground Service - is this correct? Again, I'm trying to figure out how to create "floating foreground chathead bubble/view" similar to how Facebook Messenger does it. Would a Notificationn Channel be needed for that?

Comment: Yes, you need the notification channel to display a notification in API 26+. And a foreground service requires a notification in API 26+.

Comment: Could you possibly give me a quick rundown of the steps of how I would now go about creating a foreground floating chathead, as of API-26 and above? Again, none of the libraries or examples work anymore, so I just need to know how to adjust them, or what I must add.. I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I've never done that specific thing before. But the githbub link I posted will get you the ForegroundService part.

Comment: Yea I took a look at the link you posted, but it seems pretty oriented towards retrieving location - and although it implements a foreground service, I think it's gonna end up being quite a bit different/off from what I'm needing to do.. I'm still somewhat new to certain things, so the less confusion the better, ya know what I mean lol.. I don't need my hand held, but at the same time, I sometimes find it difficult to distinguish what IS needed and what is NOT needed, from an example, based on what IM actually trying to do. I'm starting to lose hope in achieving this :/

Comment: Hey Gavin, by the way - that code snippet you posted, is that supposed to go inside a separate activity, which then launches the foregroundservice based on the API version of the User? OR, does that code go inside the Service itself? I ask because I noticed in the Intent, you put `ForegroundService.this` as the origin, as well as the destination.. Could you quickly explain why you did that? Thanks!

Comment: The example code I posted is the onCreate() method of a bound ForegroundService. So the Activity it's bound to calls bindService() instead of startService() to kick off the Service.. If you don't want a bound ForegroundService, you should be able to just call startForegroundService() from an Activity instead (and then make sure the ForegroundService still calls startForeground() in its onCreate() ).

Comment: So I would call `startForegroundService` from my Activity, just as I would normally call `startService`, and then within the onCreate of the Service, I would need to immediately call `startForeground`, correct? My only question is about the NotificationChannel and whatnot, as I am not familiar with using that, nor am I quite sure of why that is needed in my use case, other than the fact that it is required by Android Oreo.. Could you perhaps provide me a quick example of exactly how I would go about doing this with use-able code, in the Activity and Service, respectively?